# React toggle tab className active/inactive

Tags: reactjs

Can someone help me with an issue I'm having, I want to toggle the className active/inactive tab for styling purposes, but I don't know how. The functionality works, but I need the className to be active/inactive so I can style them properly. How can this be achieved?

Here is my code:

GlobalNav.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { CallToAction } from "core";
import Tabs from "../Tabs/Tabs";
import "./styles.scss";

const GlobalNav = ({ selectedTab }) => {
 const activeTab = selectedTab.toLowerCase();
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="global-nav">
        {tabLinks[activeTab]?.map(item => {
          return (
          <CallToAction
            as="button"
            format="textOnly"
            onClick={() => {}}
            className="global-nav__button"
          >
            {item.title}
          </CallToAction>
          )})}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GlobalNav;
```

Tabs.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Tab from "./Tab/Tab.jsx";

import "./styles.scss";

const Tabs = ({ tabs, activeTab }) => {
  const handleToggle = tab => {
    activeTab(tab);
    console.log('selected tab from Tabs', tab);
  };

  return (
    <div className="tabs-container">
      {tabs.map(tab => (
        <Tab key={tab} tab={tab} onToggle={handleToggle} active={activeTab} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tabs;
```

Tab.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import classnames from 'classnames';

import "./styles.scss";

const Tab = ({ active, onToggle, tab }) => {
console.log(active === tab);
  return (
    <div className="tab-container">
      <Button
        as="button"
        format="textOnly"
        onClick={() => {
          onToggle(tab);
        }}
        className={active === tab ? "tab-button-active" : "tab-button-inactive"}
      >
        {tab}
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tab;
```

I've tried to define a state on Tabs and Tab components, but did not worked correctly, both tabs were selected on page load or when clicked stays both selected.

Comment: try to pass `activeTab` prop from `Tabs` to `Tab`, and on the `className` validation do something like this `activeTab === tab ?  "tab-button-active" : "tab-button-inactive"`

Comment: @iReallyNeedYourHelp I've tried this now, but nothing happens when I click between tabs.. in console.log(active === tab) I get false always. Maybe because activeTab from Tabs is a function ?

Comment: @iReallyNeedYourHelp I've got your idea, I've passed now activeTab from GlobalNav.jsx to Tabs - > Tab and now it works. Thanks!